# How to autorefresh the page to show the seconds changing?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<script language="javascript"> 
today = new Date(); 
document.write("<BR>The time now is: ", today.getHours(),":",today.getMinutes(),":",today.getSeconds()); 
document.write("<BR>The date is: ", today.getDate(),"/",today.getMonth()+1,"/",today.getYear()); 
</script> 
</html>
```

I'd like to autorefresh the page to show the change in the seconds. How to do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably shouldn't use document.write(). It is mostly considered bad practice. You'd be better off using a container element in your HTML (e.g. a `<div>`). You can then set the `innerHTML` of this `<div>`.

Next up, you don't have to refresh the page every single second. Use a `setInterval()` function. It accepts a function and an interval that lets you set after what time the given function should be running again.

In your HTML, all you need is a `<div>` element.

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

In your JavaScript, define a function that writes the current date into the container element and use setInterval to call it every second (1000ms).

```
var time = document.getElementById('time');

function writeDate () {
    var today = new Date();
    time.innerHTML = "The time now is: " + today.getHours() +":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    time.innerHTML += "<br>The date is: " + today.getDate() + "/" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + today.getFullYear();
}

setInterval(writeDate, 1000);
```

You can see it in action in this [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vloxxity/Mb9Wq/).

Comment: @Derija93 Obviously, yes. However, when I posted mine, yours wasn't at the level of detail it is now.

Comment: Well that was a mistake. I managed to hit Tab + Enter while editing the code and it posted the answer. That was really awkward...

Answer (score 0):

Auto-refreshing here isn't a good idea. There are better approaches. However, if you insist, use:

```
window.location.reload();
```

A better way would be to wrap that in a function and call `window.setInterval` or `window.setTimeout` on it. Note that `setInterval` registers a recurring timer while `setTimeout` will call the registered function only once. Change your code like this:

```
<head>
<script language="text/javascript">
function doIt() {
    var today = new Date();
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "The time now is: " +
        today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds() + 
        "<br />The date is: " + today.getDate() + "/" + ( today.getMonth() + 1 ) +
        "/" + today.getYear();
}
window.setInterval(doIt, 1000);
// Alternatively you can use:
//window.setInterval("doIt()", 1000); // This is what you usually learn first...
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This (Note you should use `getFullYear` instead of `getYear`):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Date Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'time'><div>
        <script language="javascript">
            function getCurrentTime()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var hours = today.getHours();
                if (hours <= 9){
                    hours = '0' + hours;
                }
                var minutes = today.getMinutes();
                if (minutes <= 9){
                    minutes = '0' + minutes;
                }
                var seconds = today.getSeconds();
                if (seconds <= 9){
                    seconds = '0' + seconds;
                }
                return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            }

            function getCurrentDate()
            {
                var today = new Date();
                var days = today.getDate();
                if (days <= 9){
                    days = '0' + days;
                }
                var months = today.getMonth() + 1;
                if (months <= 9){
                    months = '0' + months;
                }
                var years = today.getFullYear();
                if (years <= 9){
                    years = '0' + years;
                }
                return days + "/" + months + "/" + years;
            }

            function updateDateTime()
            {
                document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = '<br />The time now is: ' + getCurrentTime() +
                                                            '<br />The date is: ' + getCurrentDate();
                setTimeout(updateDateTime, 1000);
            }

            updateDateTime();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use `setInterval` instead of calling `setTimeout` over and over again?

Comment: With setTimeout you will never get two instances running at the same time in the case one of them take too long to run.